# how to change the Tab focus in tabhost?

Tags: android

I am new to Android.

I am implementing coding related to tab host.

I created three tabs named tab1,tab2,tab3 in tab host.

When i am starting my application tab1 is automatically fired.

My intention is when i am starting my application tab2 is fired automatically.

with out changing thee positions.

if any one has idea please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){    
TabHost tabHost = ...;
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);//index of second tab
...
}
```

Or as an option - move a content from second tab to first one.

Comment: hi if u don't mind, this is not clear please give me a sample.Thanks For u'r reply.